# How can I convert a book's ISBN 13 to ISBN 10

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

Is there some algorithm to convert from ISBN 13 to ISBN 10? I would like to do this in vb.net.

Comment: [International Standard Book Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) Google is your Friend.  She misses you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I never used vb.net, but I found a script via Google:

```
Public Function isbn13toisbn10(ByVal isbn13)
        Dim a As Integer
        Dim b As Integer
        Dim c As Integer
        Dim d As Integer
        Dim e As Integer
        Dim f As Integer
        Dim g As Integer
        Dim h As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim l As Integer
        Dim m As Integer
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim o As Object
        Dim n2 As Integer
        Dim isbnarr(12)
        For i = 0 To 12
            isbnarr(i) = CInt(Mid(isbn13, i + 1, 1))
        Next
        a = isbnarr(0)
        b = isbnarr(1)
        c = isbnarr(2)
        d = isbnarr(3)
        e = isbnarr(4)
        f = isbnarr(5)
        g = isbnarr(6)
        h = isbnarr(7)
        i = isbnarr(8)
        j = isbnarr(9)
        k = isbnarr(10)
        l = isbnarr(11)
        m = isbnarr(12)
        n = (d * 10) + (9 * e) + (8 * f) + (7 * g) + (6 * h) + (5 * i) + (4 * j) + (3 * k) + (2 * l)
        n2 = Int((n / 11) + 1)
        o = (11 * n2) - n
        If o = 10 Then
            o = "X"
        ElseIf o = 11 Then
            o = 0
        End If
        isbn13toisbn10 = CStr(d & e & f & g & h & i & j & k & l & o)
    End Function
```

Source: http://snipplr.com/view/5127/

There are more results like this on Google, just give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, it's this.

```
if String.Compare(isbn13.Left(3),"978") then 
  isbn10 = isbn13.right(10)
else 
  isbn10 = "CANNOT CONVERT"
end
```

Remember, to convert a ISBN10 to ISBN13, you just add "978" to its front.  For those ISBN13 that start with 979, there is no true corresponding ISBN10 number.  After all, ISBN10 was technically phased out in 2007.